# Dice-rolling tool

Tags: beginner, react.js, dice, jsx

I am an experienced programmer, but a complete beginner with React. My goal is to teach myself React.

I've made a simple die-roller application. The application presents a drop-down, and the user can choose what die to roll (e.g. a d6 is a six-sided die). When the user clicks "roll", an appropriate random number is generated and displayed.

The app is working fine, but I would be grateful to know whether I've written genuinely "React-y" code; whether it's structured properly, whether I have got the naming conventions right, etc.

Some specific questions: is the "Dice" constant declared in the right place/way?
Should the "option" elements be full React components? Should the "button" be a full React component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Dice = ["4", "6", "8", "10", "12", "20"];

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      outcome: null,
      sides: null
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.setSides = this.setSides.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          Die roller
        </header>

        <DieChooser dice={Dice} setSides={this.setSides}></DieChooser>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Roll</button>
        <Result outcome={this.state.outcome} />

      </div>
    );
  }

  setSides(s) {
    this.setState({sides: s});
  }

  handleClick() {
    const rolled = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.sides)) + 1;
    this.setState({ outcome: rolled })
  }
}

class DieChooser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.props.setSides(props.dice[0]);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.setSides(e.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.props.dice.map((die) =>
          <option key={die} value={die}>d{die}</option>
        )}
      </select>
    )
  }
}

function Result (props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.outcome}</p>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: if you use arrow function like `handleClick = () => {};` in the class, you don't need to bind it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new ES6 syntax, arrow functions allow you to remove `.bind` from your code.

Don't make a stateful component if you're not using its state. Your `DieChooser` doesn't handle its value change by itself since its parent component is handling it. Make a stateless(function) component whenever you can and do not require to use lifecycle methods or a private state.

I also moved the `setSides` up to the parent to improve readability.

A `select` tag will always select the first option by default; there is no need for `this.props.setSides(props.dice[0]);`.

Props deconstructing will also make your code more readable, as the last component `Result` only takes a single line now.

Working live example :

```js
const Dice = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20];

class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   outcome: null,
   sides: null
  };
 }

 render = () => {
  return (
   <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
     Die roller
                </header>
    <DieChooser dice={Dice} setSides={this.setSides} />
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Roll</button>
    <Result outcome={this.state.outcome} />
   </div>
  );
 }

 setSides = event => {
  this.setState({ sides: event.target.value });
 }

 handleClick = ev => {
  const rolled = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.sides)) + 1;
  this.setState({ outcome: rolled })
 }
}

const DieChooser = ({ dice, setSides }) => {
 return (
  <select onChange={setSides}>
   {dice.map( die =>
    <option key={die} value={die}>d{die}</option>
   )}
  </select>
 )
}

const Result = ({ outcome }) => <p>{outcome}</p>


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```

Comment: Just few very minor things: `setSides()` (rightly) moved up in the tree but it still depends on an implementation detail (`e.target.value`). I'd rather abstract this away (if, for example, I'll change `DieChooser` to click an image in a grid...then I also have to change code here). `App` might be a `PureComponent` (not that it makes any real difference here, I just consider it a - opinionated - good habit for non functional ones).